# HTML : Getting warning - Invalid location of tag (input)

Tags: html, xhtml

I have simple form and placed it inside the **< div id="center">**. It's working fine but still getting warning. why so ?

e.g.
**< div id="center">**

```
<div id = "center">

   <form action="test" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" id="text1" name="texts"/> </input>  --> getting warning

   </form>    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An `<input>` element cannot be a child element of `<form>`. A block element needs to go there.

You need something like `form --> fieldset --> input` or `form --> div --> input`.

You also have a self-closing `<input />` followed by an end tag `</input>` which doesn't have an open input to close.

Comment: form --> div --> input :) resolved by using this method.   thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have already closed the input tag

```
<input type="hidden" id="text1" name="texts"/>
```

Written in this form is a self-closing tag. There is no need to close it in explicit form.
Plus input must be inside a block container.
Check the example here http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.4

Answer (score 0):

by putting the `<input type="text" ... />` within a `<div>` block like this makes the error go away in eclipse or spring tool suite.  following is a very basic example.

```
<div>
    username:<input type="text" name="user" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you seems to have mistakenly tried to close a single input tag twice.
`<input type="hidden" id="text1" name="texts"/> </input>`.

Here, `/>` is a self closing tag,
and `</input>` is closing the tag explicitly.

Please note that `input` is a void element. And a void element can never have any contents under any circumstances. Although, void elements can have attributes.
So, its a good practice to avoid closing such tags explicitly.

Secondly, enclose the `<input type="hidden" id="text1" name="texts"/>` within a block element like

```
<div>
   <input type="hidden" id="text1" name="texts"/>
</div>
```